# Get ALL rows where more than X entries for column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of books in a MySQL database with Title and Author columns. I need to select ALL of the books that have an Author who has more than X books in the table.

Here's an example of the desired output:

```
| Author        | Title                |
|---------------|----------------------|
| Dan Brown     | Angels and Demons    |
| Dan Brown     | The Da Vinci Code    |
| Robert Ludlum | The Bourne Identity  |
| Robert Ludlum | The Bourne Supremacy |
```

I can get one book per Author using a simple group by and having condition:

```
SELECT * FROM books
GROUP BY author
HAVING count(author) > 1
ORDER BY author;
```

Which gives the following output:

```
| Author        | Title                |
|---------------|----------------------|
| Dan Brown     | Angels and Demons    |
| Robert Ludlum | The Bourne Identity  |
```

How can I get a list of books with an Author that has more than X books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE author IN (
  SELECT author
    FROM books
    GROUP BY author
    HAVING COUNT(author) > 1
  )
```

Comment: This is exceptionally slow on large amounts of data. Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Do you have an index on author?

Comment: I didn't. Indexing author made it significantly faster though. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your query as a [sub-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE Author IN (
    SELECT Author
    FROM books
    GROUP BY Author
    HAVING COUNT(Author) > 1
) ORDER BY Author, Title;
```

If you want to get a simple (comma seperated) list of books per author you can also use the following solution using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT Author, GROUP_CONCAT(Title) AS title_list
FROM books
GROUP BY Author
HAVING COUNT(Author) > 1
ORDER BY Author;
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10d80f/2/0

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using an in...

```
SELECT [Author] , [Title]
  FROM [books] b
  where [Author] in 
  (select Author from [books] group by [Author]
       having count(Author) >1)
```

Answer (score 0):

a very simple query will be like below

```
SELECT books.Title
FROM (SELECT Count(books.Author) AS CountOfAuthor, books.Author AS A
FROM books
GROUP BY books.Author )  AS bookByAuthor INNER JOIN books ON bookByAuthor.A = 
books.Author
WHERE (((books.Author)=[bookByAuthor].[A]));
```

hope this helps